# How do you as product owner decide that a product is feasible?

Tags: product-owner, stakeholders

You as a product owner just got an idea from a stakeholder and need to decide if it's feasible? What steps should you follow in order to make sure the product is not going to be a total fail?
Note: Stakeholder really believes in the idea but you are responsible for selling the idea to the development team with right arguments for success

Comment: Assumming the Stakeholder convinced you, what makes you think the developers won't be convinced? Why can't you use the same arguments & data?

Comment: me as a PO I need to believe in it that is feasible in order to go to the team. What stepts should I follow?

Comment: What steps you should follow so *you* are convinced? I don't know, wouldn't that be up to *you* to determine?

Comment: Are you asking how you determine the MVP, market fit, or the practical requirements and consequences of the technical implementation? These are very different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you as product owner decide that a product is feasible?

Ideally, you should "determine", not "decide". If you have an idea or you have identified a need that a product can meet, then you can do a Product Feasibility Study/Analysis and try to gather some data for various KPIs you might be interested in (these will vary depending on what you are interested in).

The data you collect will help you validate some of the assumptions you may have, and stop the project if something seems amiss. But even if the data is good, nothing is a guarantee for success; you will find out when you build it and release it (one recent example comes to mind: [CNN+](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNN%2B)).

> Stakeholder really believes in the idea but you are responsible for selling the idea to the development team with right arguments for success

You use the results from the previous feasibility analysis.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really good question and one that doesn't get asked enough!

Some things you can do to gain confidence in the feasibility of an idea:

- Build a business case for the idea (testing likely value versus likely cost)
- Build a prototype or a mock up that allows you to gauge customer response
- Build a [minimum viable product (MVP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) - something that is just functional enough for you to gain valuable feedback

It is also important to run the idea by the development team to check the *technical feasibility* of the idea.